# Update the dashboard.config through my package

Tags: c#, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created my own application/section using the sectionservice called from within my package. I am now trying to add a html/angular dashboard view to this section but all the tutorials I find are about editing the dashboard.config and adding the pointer to the view here.

As my aim is to create a standalone package I don't want to edit this file directly but add a dashboard to my section pragmatically.

Is this possible? could anyone link me to a tutorial or hint at what services I should be using.

---

*I don't know how applicable this is but I have been requested to paste my code for creating the original section.*

```
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;

namespace Labs.App_Plugins.StueyLabs
{
    public class StueyLabsSection : ApplicationEventHandler
    {

        protected const string stueyLabsSectionAlias = "stueyLabs";

        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbraco, ApplicationContext context)
        {

            // Gets a reference to the section (if already added)
            Section section = context.Services.SectionService.GetByAlias(stueyLabsSectionAlias);
            if (section != null) return;

            // Add a new "Stuey" section
            context.Services.SectionService.MakeNew("Stuey Labs", stueyLabsSectionAlias, "icon-stuey");

            // Grant all existing users access to the new section
            context.Services.UserService.AddSectionToAllUsers(stueyLabsSectionAlias);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: What code would you like? my section? To me this me this doesn't seem relevant to dashboard views but I will do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This may help anyone else who is trying to do something similar to me. As of writing Umbraco does not have a code first option for adding dashboards out of the box.

Two solutions have been suggested:

1. Package actions

   These will run when others install you package, injecting xml into the dashboard.config in order to customise views.

   https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/dashboards/
2. Skybrud.Umbraco.Dashboard

   This seems to be a plugin you can install through NuGet which allows you to manipulate dashboard in Umbraco 7 all through c#.

   https://github.com/abjerner/Skybrud.Umbraco.Dashboard

I am opting for route one and will update this answer with any useful resources once I am happy with my results.